# Ethereum conferences?

Tags: devcon

This is a similar question like the [Statistics Conferences question at CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/statistics-conferences)

What are the most significant **annual Ethereum conferences**?

Rules:

> - Include a link to the conference
> - Please include links for the talks (be it youtube, the conference site or some other video streaming site)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are currently no regularly recurring conferences devoted to Ethereum or smart contracts, however, Ethereum Foundation and EthDev organizations have put on 2 conferences: DEVCON0 and DEVCON1 to-date.

**DEVCON0**:

- November 10-14, 2014
- Berlin, Germany
- Approximately 50 in attendance, primarily core developers
- [11 recorded talks on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJqWcTqh_zKEjpSej3ddtDOKPRGl_7MhS)

[image: Group photo from DEVCON0 on 14 November 2014]

**DEVCON1**:

- November 9-13, 2015
- London, England
- Approximately 400 in attendance, including general admission
- [80 recorded talks on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJqWcTqh_zKHQUFX4IaVjWjfT2tbS4NVk)

Nether conference has a permanent website, although the remains of the DEVCON1 site are still online at https://devcon.ethereum.org/

Answer (score 3):

**DEVCON2** will be [somewhere in Asia](https://twitter.com/vitalikbuterin/status/696493262924816385) this fall, according to vitalik buterin.

[image: twitter screenshot]

Edit: Shanghai Sept/19-23, 2016, https://ethereumfoundation.org/devcon/

Answer (score 0):

Its here Blockchain Week in Shanghai: September 19-21 22 demo day 23-34 expo http://www.blockchainweek2016.org/index_en.html

I am going to present: From centralized startups to decentralized foundups on the blockchain.